# Get the path using regex in .each iterator

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, iterator

Where do I need to put my regex `/\/([^\)]+)\//` in the code below to get only `block1` and `block2` paths from my full paths in a given array?

```
def path_from_array(array)
  array.each do |var|
    yield var
  end
end

puts path_from_array(['path/block1/something', 'path/block2']) { |x| x.to_s }
```

Now the output is:

```
path/block1/something
path/block2/
```

and I need:

```
block1
block2
```

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking - are you asking how to use regex?

Comment: How to use it in my iterator which gets the block. I need somehow using regex to get only my 'blocks' from full path names in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think you are using the wrong regex first, try using this regex instead:

```
/\/(.*)\//
```

Secondly, to use regex you need something similar to this:

```
def path_from_array(array)
  array.each do |var|
     if ( var =~ /\/(.*)\// )
        puts var.scan(/\/(.*)\//);
     end
  end
end

puts path_from_array(['path/block1/something', 'path/block2']) { |x| x.to_s }
```

For an explanation:

- `var =~` will find regex and return a boolean.
- `var.scan` will return the match found.

Here are a few resources on regex and Ruby:

- "[Ruby Regular Expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm)"
- "[Using Regular Expressions in Ruby — Part 2 of 3](https://www.blueboxcloud.com/insight/blog-article/using-regular-expressions-in-ruby-part-2-of-3)"

Comment: Use `%r` to avoid leaning-toothpick syndrome: `/\/(.*)\//  # => /\/(.*)\//`
so use `%r!/(.*)/!  # => /\/(.*)\//` which results in the same regex.

Comment: Thank you, so there no need to use yield?

Comment: actually I would probably use yield, I was only using "puts" to debug the line

Answer (score 1):

No regex is needed:

```
['path/block1/something', 'path/block2'].map { |path|
  path.split('/')[1]
} # => ["block1", "block2"]
```

Regular expressions are great, but not everything is a good use for them.

If you're going to process paths containing Windows or *nix paths, on those OSes, then you'll want your code to automatically adjust depending on the OS:

```
path.split(File::SEPARATOR)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to use method instead of only `.map`

Comment: Then put the line in the block inside your method.